# how to convert JSON characters like \\u00e1 to their original character in perl

Tags: perl

i am using perl  and got a json format for parsing.I used Json::XS for parsing Json format in perl.
Now I  want that characters like \u00e1 get converted to á .how do i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Parsing JSON with that data **will** give you that character.

Perhaps you just need to properly encode the output?

```
perl -MJSON::XS -E'binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");say shift JSON::XS::decode_json(q|["\u00e1"]|)'
```

Comment: cant we use pack unpack for this conversion

Comment: What conversion? The one that JSON::XS has *already done* for you?